# Call twitter Webservice using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, twitter

Hello I am trying to call a web service of Twitter using pure html and java script.
so i have tried to use jQuery.

here is my sample code ...

where i m mistaking ... please help ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lookup</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function callWebService(){
        alert("Hello . . ");

        $.ajax({
            url:'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=gloriahansen',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success:function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }   
        });

        alert("Hello . . . . . . . . .");
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="ajax">
      Put Stuff in Me
    </h1>

    <Button onclick="callWebService();">Call Web Service</Button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't reinvent the wheel. ;) 
Use this plugin http://code.google.com/p/jquery-twit/

Answer (score 1):

Because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you can't send HTTP request to foreign domains. You can use jsonp to circumvent this. There's an example at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

AJAX can not go cross domain, you need to use what is called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).
In other words, you are using the wrong function for the job. [This one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead should sort you out.